# what is wrong with my SQL code? It shows Error Code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to find the problem. But unfortunately I can't. The error show in the INSERT TABLE line as=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1 & also Data truncated for column 'Course_Credit' at row 21. TIA.

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB;

USE testDB;

CREATE TABLE COURSE (
    COURSE_ID VARCHAR(255),
    COURSE_TITLE VARCHAR(255),
    COURSE_CREDIT DOUBLE(255, 2)
);

INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSE_ID, COURSE_TITLE, COURSE_CREDIT)
VALUES ('CSE-101', 'Introduction to Computer Systems', '1.00'),
       ('CSE-102', 'Introduction to Computer Systems (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('EEE-105', 'Introduction to Electrical Engineering', '2.00'),
       ('EEE-106', 'Introduction to Electrical Engineering (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('ME-100', 'Mechanical Engineering Drawing-I', '1.50'),
       ('ME-101', 'Mechanical Engineering', '2.00'),
       ('ME-102', 'Mechanical Engineering (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('MATH-101', 'Differential Calculas And Co-ordinate Geometry', '3.00'),
       ('PHY-101', 'Physics', '3.00'),
       ('PHY-102', 'Physics (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('CSE-201', 'Structured Programming Language', '3.00'),
       ('CSE-202', 'Structured Programming Language (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('CSE-203', 'Discrete Mathematics', '3.00'),
       ('MATH-201', 'Integral Calculus, Differential Equations and Series', '3.00'),
       ('CHEM-201', 'Chemistry', '3.00'),
       ('CHEM-202', 'Chemistry (Sessional)', '1.50'),
       ('ENG-201', 'English', '2.00'),
       ('ENG-202', 'Communication in English (Practice)', '1.00'),
       ('SS-201', 'Government and Public Administration', '2.00'),
       ('CSE-301', 'Object Oriented Programming Language', '3.00'),
       ('CSE-302', 'Object Oriented Programming Language (Sessional)', '1,50'),
       ('CSE-303', 'Data Structures', '3.00'),
       ('CSE-304', 'Data Structures', '1.50'),
       ('MATH-301', 'Complex Variable and Statistics', '3.00');
```

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error at the `use`. Check for odd characters? Or check your version of MySQL? You're getting "truncated" because you're inserting `'1,50'` as a `double` (note the comma). Also, quotes around numbers is unnecessary and requires an extra conversion. Also, `double` precision will not go to 255. It will go to 53. It's largely unnecessary. Perhaps you want a `numeric` instead?

Comment: you have a comma in a numeric field 1.50  not 1,50

Comment: @scaisEdge Your edit to remove the comma materially altered the question. I've rolled it back.

Comment: @Schwern   thanks  .. i have edited  in  wrong manner  .. thank for rolback

Comment: @Schwern Thanks a lot. It Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comma (",") inside the value for the column - COURSE_CREDIT in the row #21:
*('CSE-302', 'Object Oriented Programming Language (Sessional)', '1,50')*

Change the value to 1.50 .... it should work